# В цикле должен быть switch который будет принимать сгенерированное рандомом число

Tags: java

Доброго времени суток делал домашнюю работу и столкнулся с такой вот проблемой
Я создал класс Squad в нем есть поля, конструктор и есть массив этот массив надо в цыкле заполнить случайными персонажами из другого класса (HeroesTypes):

```
public class HeroesTypes {
    public static final int PALADIN = 0;
    public static final int BERSERK = 1;
    public static final int ELF = 2;
    public static final int HUNTER = 3;
    public static final int WARLOCK = 4;
    public static final int WIZARD = 5;
}
```

и потом в цикле должен быть switch который будет принимать сгенерированное 
рандомное число. В кейсах это число должно сравниваться с 
константами из класса HeroesTypes. И в текущую ячейку массива должен 
создаваться и добавляться соответствующий тип персонажа.

```
public class Squad {

    private Hero[] heroes;
    private int size;
    private Random rd;

    public Squad(int size) {
        this.size = size; 
        rd = new Random();
        heroes = new Hero[6];
        for(int i = 0; i < heroes.length; i++){

        }
    }

}
```

код класса Hero

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package base;

import java.util.Random;

/**
 *
 * @author Pivar
 */
public abstract class Hero {

    final String NAME;
    protected int health;
    protected int strenght;
    protected boolean alive;

    public Hero(String name, int health, int strenght) {
        this.NAME = name;
        this.health = health;
        this.strenght = strenght;
        if (health > 0) {
            this.alive = true;
        }
    }

    public int getHealth() {
        return health;
    }

    public void setHealth(int health) {
        this.health = health;
    }

    public int getStrenght() {
        return strenght;
    }

    public void setStrenght(int strenght) {
        this.strenght = strenght;
    }

    public boolean isAlive() {
        return alive;
    }

    public void setAlive(boolean alive) {
        this.alive = alive;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Hero{" + "NAME=" + NAME + ", health=" + health + ", strenght=" + strenght + ", alive=" + alive + '}';
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        return super.equals(obj); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return super.hashCode(); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

    public void damage(int inAttack) {
        int min = 1;
        int max = 3;
        int dif = max - min;
        Random rd = new Random();
        inAttack = rd.nextInt(dif + 1);
        inAttack += min;
        this.health -= inAttack;
        if (this.health <= 0) {
            this.alive = false;
        }

    }

    public void attack(Hero att) {
        att.damage(health);
    }
}
```

Класс Warrior наследующий из Hero

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package specialty;

import base.Hero;

/**
 *
 * @author Pivar
 */
public abstract class Warrior extends Hero {

    public Warrior(String name, int health, int strenght) {
        super(name, health, strenght);
    }

}
```

Класс Berserker наследующий из Warrior
        /*

```
* To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package types;

import specialty.Warrior;

/**
 *
 * @author Pivar
 */
public final class Berserk extends Warrior {

    public Berserk(String name, int health, int strenght) {
        super(name, health, strenght);
    }

}
```

Comment: В чем проблема ? Не можете реализовать switch ?

Comment: да свитч я знаю но не знаю что бы он принимал генерировал и добавлял в каждую ячейку массива соответствующий тип персонажа

Comment: Код класса Hero ? Какая у вас реализация ? У вас классы-наследники персонажей? Пока не ясно, откуда брать значение, которое надо записывать в массив

Comment: я добавил код класса hero он есть родителем классов: Archer, Mage,Warrior а те родители еще 6 под классов

Comment: Можете привести пример еще одного класса из 6 классов ?

Comment: добавил класс Warrior и Berserker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Что то на подобии вот этого ?В switch генерация рандомного числа от 0 до 5 включительно, потом выбор по константе, после запись в текущий элемент массива объекта

```
 public Squad(int size) {
                this.size = size; 
                heroes = new Hero[6];
                for(int i = 0; i < heroes.length; i++){
    switch(0 + (int) (Math.random() * 6)){
    case HeroesTypes.PALADIN:
    heroes[i] = new Paladin("Christian",100,50);
    break;
    case HeroesTypes.BERSERK:
    heroes[i] = new Berserk("Christian",100,50);
    break;
    case HeroesTypes.ELF:
    heroes[i] = new Elf("Christian",100,50);
    break;
    case HeroesTypes.HUNTER:
    heroes[i] = new Hunter("Christian",100,50);
    break;
    case HeroesTypes.WARLOCK:
    heroes[i] = new Warlock("Christian",100,50);
    break;
    case HeroesTypes.WIZARD:
    heroes[i] = new Wizard("Christian",100,50);
    break;
                }
            }
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, хотел бы спросить еще кое что я учусь сам и ищу помощи от кого либо и вопрос нехочешь мне помочь при разных вопросах?

Comment: @ЕвгенийВалерьевич , выкладывайте вопросы, как вы сделали сейчас, по возможности буду стараться,отслеживать их и помогать вам. Если вопрос небольшой, не связан с кучей кода и тд, тогда просто в комментарии мне отпишите, как сейчас

Comment: спасибо большое !

Comment: @ЕвгенийВалерьевич удачи в изучении )